# What is UNIX and what is the relation of it with Linux

Tags: system

When I hear linux I always hear UNIX, Solaris and GNU and frankly I don't understand any word of this only Linux, so could some one explain to me what is each one?

Answer (score 2):

The complete answer, about difference between this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix-like

- Linux = Kernel
- GNU = It's a project about Software Libre
- Solaris = OS like Unix

:)

Comment: I had always been told GNU = Gnu's Not Unix

Comment: The GNU operating system is meant to be a free/libre replacement for Unix. Technically, GNU's Not Unix (Which is what GNU stands for), but it is meant to be similar enough to Unix that Unix users can switch. It's also designed to be compatible with unix, so one can run Unix programs.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a somewhat more detailed poster, I vaguely remember, but for a quick summary, that should be enough:

[image: Unix history-simple]
Image from [Wikimedia commons: Unix history-simple](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Unix_history-simple.png)

(For the details (all), see [GNU/Linux Distribution Timeline 12.10](http://futurist.se/gldt/))